# Default Configuration in Dell 5548

Tags: dell, powerconnect

I am new to Dell switches and have recently joined a company. There are two IP addresses configured on a 5548 PowerConnect.

```
ip address 192.168.0.5 255.255.252.0
ip address 192.168.137.17 255.255.255.0
```

and default gateway is mentioned as

```
ip default-gateway 192.168.137.1
```

However we are not using the 192.168.137.x subnet. Are these ip addresses default configuration already present on switches?

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

There's no default gw defined by default on Powerconnect 5500 series switches.  Use `no ip default-gateway` command to remove or `ip default-gateway <gw address>` to change.  The CLI manual is [here.](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/Common/PowerConnect5500_CLIRef_en-us.pdf)  Sounds like it would be a good thing to read up on.

Comment: And just for completeness: In the default configuration, a DELL PC5500 Series switch has no IP configured. It is per-default set to receive a DHCP IP on vlan 1